# Which server side technology to use for a small business website?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to decide what's the best framework for my small web project:

PHP, Django (or some more ligthweight Python libraries), Ruby on Rails? Or something else? (Except ASP.NET and JSP, because I don't like those)

I want to use the latest HTML5 features, no Flash, heavy JS and AJAX, and lots of animations. I would also like to write a custom picture slideshow using CSS3 and JS. I wan't to hand code all the client side myself but I don't know what to use on the server side. I won't need databases or much of the webapplication framework features, only something simple for managing templates and urls and serving AJAX requests.

Comment: "heavy JS and AJAX, and lots of animations" - so you want your page to be slow, and irritate your users? Are you making another Twitter?

Comment: Don't worry I wont have many users to irritate. I want to sell the products of the company and have a cool looking modern site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Almost Everything is Possible with :

```
PHP
+
jQuery
+
HTML5
+
CSS3
```

Answer (score 3):

**the best language is the one that you can understand**

**in my case, asp.net is considered more "enterprise" than php, but I will probably write more bugs, errors, in asp.net comparing to the same code written in php.**

so if you know a language, keep use it, any server language can do the same things that the other ones do.

in second place, documentation is fundamental. I use for work a lot of languages, and i think the php's documentation is simply the better one. users contributions in php's docs are really useful.

java's doc is more complicated and schematic but there are a lot of tutorials on the net.

microsoft's msdn is a little painful, but it is not so bad if you have learned how to search infos.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel adventurous you could look at http://nodejs.org/ and http://expressjs.com/ 
or even http://couchdb.apache.org/, with the latter you could run everything off a JSON and Javascript driven non relational database.

PS. I believe at the beginning of your third paragraph you meant "I want".

Comment: I like these. I'm going to read up on them and maybe choose one of these instead of PHP..

Answer (score 1):

I always normally use,

PHP - Easy to learn, easy to work with...

JQuery - Awesome library and easy to learn...

Using HTML5 would also let you draw and animate images with canvas which is also awesome and easy to pick up!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is the best choice. easy to learn, open source and etc. More imporantly you can get many online tutorial as well as you will get answer quickly for your queries